# Optimizing for loop for using dictionary values to format new fasta files

Tags: python, loops, optimization, fasta

I have a for loop that does what I need, however, Im wondering if the loop could be further optimized.

I have a dictionary, where each key has a list of values associated with it. The list of values are basically accession numbers. For each key, id like to loop through my fasta file, and create a new fasta file with only the sequences whos accession number are in the list of values for each given key.

The loop I have so far is as fallows...

```
seqs=open('file_name.fasta', 'r')
seq_lines=seqs.readlines()

for i in d.keys():
    fasts=open(i,'w')
    for index, line in enumerate(seq_lines):
        for j in d[i]: #loops thru the accession number (ie lis of values for each key) 
            if (j in line): #checks to see if acc number is in fasta file
                header=seq_lines[index] #the header from fasta file
                nuc=seq_lines[index+1] # The sequence after each header
                fasts.write(header.rstrip()+'\n'+nuc)
```

d is my dictionary and seq_lines is the fasta file. This loop works fine, however it is slow when there are lots of sequences for any given key (the fasta file has around 50000 seq in total). Appreciate any input.

Example of data

This is the dictionary with the list of values
d={'range1': ['MZ193866', 'OK234148'], 'range2': ['MZ371332', 'MZ315819']}

Fasta file, with the values in the header (its a text file, not sure how to upload it directly)

seq='>MZ193866 \n ATGTTTTATTATTT \n >MZ371332 \n GGGGCTTCTATTTCCA \n > OK234148 \n AGGGCTTTTAAAAA \n >MZ315819 \n ATTTTCCCCGGGGAAAAA'

By the end Id like to have file names after the keys, containing only the sequences that are in its list of values ...

range1 = '>MZ193866 \n ATGTTTTATTATTT \n > OK234148 \n AGGGCTTTTAAAAA'

range2 = '>MZ371332 \n GGGGCTTCTATTTCCA \n >MZ315819 \n ATTTTCCCCGGGGAAAAA'

Comment: As an aside, you need to close those files when done so that the data is flushed and resources are freed. Perhaps `with open(i,'w') as fasts:`.

Comment: Is accession number something you could break out of the header and put into an indexing dictionary? If so, process the fasta file once and have a speedy lookup.

Comment: It's hard to understand what is going on without being able to run the code. I think you would get better answers if you shared an example of the dictionary and the data. I think it makes sense to avoid writing to file in a loop as much as possible, so maybe it is possible to collect all the data and then write it at once in the main for loop.

Comment: How many keys are in `d`?  Can you provide a small sample of `d` and `file_name.fasta`?

Comment: There are about 5 keys and each has a list that is around 10000 long. I can try to see if I can upload a sample.

Comment: The way to make this faster is with grouping and indexing. Most of us don't know what an accession number is and how its encoded in a fasta header. As long as the header is delimited by ">", it should be easy to group. But you gotta give us a small peek at the data. A dict with 2 keys and 2 values apiece. Two records in the fasta file.

Comment: can a sequence be in more than one accession?

Comment: Do you mean can the same accession value be across multiple keys? Because in the actual dictionary it can be. I didn't include that in the sample dataset though.

Comment: can `"MZ193866"` potentially be in `"range1"` and `"range2"`?

Comment: Yes it can @JonSG. Although in this dictionary it isn't in both.

Comment: There is a lot of extra spacing in your input data, like ` \n > OK234148 \n `. Does that need to be reproduced in the output, or would a more conformant output without things like a space after "." would be more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by each header, extract the accession number and use that as an index to the fasta records. Now, instead of scanning all records for each number of interest, you can lookup in the index.

Here, I've used a regular expression to parse the header - it's very specific to this one fasta format. A fasta with multiple values would be more complex.

```
from itertools import groupby
import re

# single column fasta header with optional whitespace before >
hdr_match = re.compile(r"\s*>").match
hdr_extract = re.compile(r"\s*>\s*([^\s]+)").match

# test data
d={'range1': ['MZ193866', 'OK234148'], 'range2': ['MZ371332', 'MZ315819']}

open("file_name_test.fasta", "w").write(""">MZ193866 
 ATGTTTTATTATTT 
 >MZ371332 
 GGGGCTTCTATTTCCA 
 > OK234148 
 AGGGCTTTTAAAAA 
 >MZ315819 
 ATTTTCCCCGGGGAAAAA
 """)

# fasta header is a single (whatever its called)
# e.g., " >MZ193866 \n" (note the non-conforming space starting some headers)

fasta_index = {}

for is_hdr, lines in groupby(open('file_name_test.fasta'), hdr_match):
    if is_hdr:
        hdr = hdr_extract(next(lines)).group(1)
    else:
        fasta_index[hdr] = "".join(line.strip() for line in lines)

for name, values in d.items():
    with open(name, "w") as fasts:
        for value in values:
            if value in fasta_index:
                fasts.write(f">{value}\n{fasta_index[value]}\n")

print("------- output -------")
for name in d:
    print(name)
    print(open(name).read())
    print("--------")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of learning points / accelerants here.  A couple of key concepts:

1. Limit the looping.  Right now you are looping over all of your sequence data for each key in your `d`.  So, if you have 50k sequences, and 100 keys, you have 5M loop executions.  You should (and can) loop over everything once for a total of 50,100 executions
2. Searching for strings in strings is *expensive*.  Right now, you are searching everything (including the sequences) for the key value, which may be error prone and is certainly expensive.  Work with the starting character `>` to identify lines of interest, and process them carefully.
3. (back to #1 a bit)  Looping through lists for matches is expensive.  In your current code you are actually 3-nested in the for loop which is (to continue the earlier example) 50k x 100 (keys of interest) x 10k (accession numbers) ~ 50B executions.  Matching groups of things should be done with sets wherever possible, which is nearly instantaneous (longer discussion).
4. You should only be opening files if you already know you have something to write.  And, as mentioned in the comments, you need to close them.  The `with` context manager handles that part for you.

So the below code loads all of the sequence data into memory, which should be doable for 50K sequences easily unless the sequences are ginormous.

It also has a parser for the header to look for Accession Number between pipe symbols, but I've just made that "optional" based on your example data above, so it will look for them but if not there, just assume the header *is* the accession number.  Note:  If you can't cleanly parse out the number from other stuff in the header, you may need to revert to string searching, but I'm guessing the headers are well structured.

##### Data file (dummy.fasta)  (*odd spacing just to test*)

```
> sp|4456
ABCDEFGHIJK
> sp| 5688 | stuff
DEFGHAEAGHHGAHA
KRKABC
>sp|XR650L   | other stuff
IIJJHYUXY
HHGGF


>   pir | JH880
BBBBDDDEEEFFFF

>pir|777|nonsense
EEEFFFHHHJJINIIIJIJIJI

> MN5502
UUUMNNMNNNNDDD
SSSTTYUAB
```

##### Code:

```
# capture all the data into a dictionary...
sequences = {}  # accession : (header, sequence)
with open('dummy.fasta', 'r') as src:
    # set up a loop
    accession_num = None
    curr_sequence = None
    line = src.readline()
    while line:
        # search for ">"
        if line[0] == '>':
            # if we were building a sequence, it is now done, add it...
            if curr_sequence:
                sequences[accession_num] = (curr_header, curr_sequence)
                accession_num = None
                curr_sequence = None

            # found a new header, now get the accession number
            curr_header = line.strip()
            tokens = line.split('|')  # tokenize the line based on pipe symbol
            if len(tokens) > 1:  # found pipe symbols
                tokens = [t.strip() for t in tokens]
                accession_num = tokens[1]  # ASSUMES that it is in the 2nd slot
            # might implement some check here on validity of the number captured...
            else:
                # assume the whole thing is the Accession Number (per example)
                accession_num = curr_header.replace('>','').strip()  # remove the > and any preceeding whitespace

        elif accession_num:  # only need to go here if we already have a number
            # keep building the sequence
            if curr_sequence is None:
                # start a new one
                curr_sequence = ''
            if len(line) > 0:
                curr_sequence += line.strip()  # the strip() removes whitespace and newline chars at ends
        line = src.readline()  # <- this will be None when empty, killing the loop

    # need to add the last one
    if curr_header and curr_sequence:
        sequences[accession_num] = (curr_header, curr_sequence)
for k in sequences: # for testing...
    print(k, sequences[k])
stuff_of_interest = {'k1': {'JH880', '5688'},
                     'k2': {'4456', '99999999999'},
                     'k3': {'4456', '5688', 'XR650L', 'JH880', 'MN5502'}}

# match stuff_of_interest to sequences and write results
for k in stuff_of_interest.keys():
    matched_keys = stuff_of_interest[k] & sequences.keys()
    # check for things that matched nothing:  a problem?
    non_matches = stuff_of_interest[k] - sequences.keys()
    if non_matches:
        print(f'failed to match these accession numbers for key {k}: {non_matches}')
    if matched_keys:
        # open a file and write it...
        f_name = '.'.join([k, 'fasta'])
        with open(f_name, 'w') as f_out:
            for k in matched_keys:
                f_out.write(sequences[k][0])
                f_out.write('\n')

                # and the sequence
                f_out.write(sequences[k][1])
                f_out.write('\n')
```

##### k3.fasta (one of the output files)

```
> sp|4456
ABCDEFGHIJK
>sp|XR650L   | other stuff
IIJJHYUXYHHGGF
> MN5502
UUUMNNMNNNNDDDSSSTTYUAB
> sp| 5688 | stuff
DEFGHAEAGHHGAHAKRKABC
>   pir | JH880
BBBBDDDEEEFFFF
```